# Retrieving and moving the last record in each group

Tags: mysql

There is a table `posts` that contains data as shown below: (`cover` column doesn't have data for now)

```
id   title      cover
-----------------------
1    title       -
2    title       -
```

And this is my `images` table :

```
id     url     post_id
-----------------------
1    1.jpg       1
2    2.jpg       1
3    3.jpg       1
4    4.jpg       1
5    5.jpg       2
6    6.jpg       2
```

I want to **move** the last record of each group to its own column in `posts` table.(last records should be deleted from `images` table and get inserted into `posts` table) So the query should be able to result as followed :

```
id   title      cover
-----------------------
1    title     4.jpg
2    title     6.jpg
```

Comment: @blank Exactly. it should be deleted .I edited my text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your expected result, you can use `update join` to do that,

```
update posts p
join (
    select t1.post_id, t1.url
    from images t1
    join (
        select max(id) max_id, post_id from images group by post_id
    ) t2 on t1.post_id = t2.post_id and t1.id = t2.max_id
) t on p.id = t.post_id
set p.cover = t.url
```

see [**demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1b161/1) here.

Also, if you want to delete 'last' image from table `images`, you can use `delete`:

```
delete t1
from images t1
join (select max(id) max_id, post_id from images group by post_id) t2
on t1.post_id = t2.post_id
and t1.id = t2.max_id
```

If you want to run these two query in one query, just create a procudure include these two query will work.

Answer (score 0):

By using **`NOT EXISTS`** get the rows having the max `id` in `images` table. Then join it with the `posts` table.

**Query**

```
select t1.`id`, t1.`title`, t2.`url`
from `posts` t1
join (
  select `id`, `url`, `post_id`
  from `images` t1
  where not exists (
    select 1 from `images` t2
    where t2.`post_id` = t1.`post_id`
    and t2.`id` > t1.`id`
  ) 
) t2
on t1.`id` = t2.`post_id`;
```

**[Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5eeea/1)**